# PHP script fails after a week with SMTP error 10055

Tags: php, apache, email, phpmailer

I have a REST PHP script (running on Apache on Windows server 2012 R2) using PHPMailer to send mails via a Postfix SMTP server on another machine.

The mailing works flawlessly until after approximately a week (50-100 email messages) when the mailing abruptly cease to work. Any further attempts to send mails results in an SMTP ERROR:

> Failed to connect to server: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full. (10055)

Looking at the Postfix server logs, Apache server logs and PHP logs yields nothing of interest, no errors pop up. Sending mails via other means using the mail server works, even from the same machine. At this point we restart the Apache server running PHP, making everything work again for another week.

From what I have been able to find, this error is the result of the TCP buffers on the machine being full. And that is typically because connections are opened and then not closed again. Other than PHPMailer the PHP script does not do any network communication.

So my question is if there is some sort of connection handling I have to take care of, do I have to close handles or similar in PHPMailer when I'm done sending a mail (something that isn't shown in the examples)? Do a configuration change somewhere? I'm a C++ programmer with limited knowledge of the internal workings of PHP.

Here is the relevant parts of the script:

```
<?php

require '../../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

abstract class Status {
    const SUCCESS = 0;
    const FAILED = 1;
    const ABORTED = 2;
    const INVALID = 3;
}

class JobController extends MyController
{
    public function postAction($request) {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public function putAction($request) {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public function deleteAction($request) {
        // Make sure there is a job id at the end of the url
        if (count($request->url_elements) != 3)
            return new Result(404, array('message' => 'Invalid command'));

        // Initialize the session and check if it is set
        if (!$this->mySessionStart())
            return new Result(401, array('message' => 'Not logged in'));

        // Check if the mirror parameter exists
        $mirror = null;
        if (isset($request->parameters['mirror']))
            $mirror = base64_decode($request->parameters['mirror']);

        // Check that status parameter exists
        if (!isset($request->parameters['result']))
            return new Result(400, array('message' => 'Missing result parameter'));

        // Parse status parameter
        if (strcasecmp($request->parameters['result'], 'success') === 0)
            $status = Status::SUCCESS;
        else if (strcasecmp($request->parameters['result'], 'failed') === 0)
            $status = Status::FAILED;
        else if (strcasecmp($request->parameters['result'], 'aborted') === 0)
            $status = Status::ABORTED;
        else
            $status = Status::INVALID;

        // Check that the status value is valid
        if ($status === Status::INVALID)
            return new Result(400, array('message' => 'Invalid result value'));

        // Check that download parameter exists if status is 'success'
        if (($status == Status::SUCCESS) && !isset($request->parameters['download']))
            return new Result(400, array('message' => 'Missing download parameter'));

        // Check that reason parameter exists if status is 'failed'
        if (($status == Status::FAILED) && !isset($request->parameters['reason']))
            return new Result(400, array('message' => 'Missing reason parameter'));

        $jobid = $request->url_elements[2];
        $filepath = ACTIVE_JOBS_PATH . $jobid . '.json';

        if (!file_exists($filepath))
            return new Result(404, array('message' => 'Unknown job'));

        $templates = __DIR__ . '\\..\\templates\\';

        if ($status === Status::SUCCESS) {
            $str = file_get_contents($filepath);
            $json = $this->decodeJson($str);
            $email_addr = $json['userEmail'];
            $name = $json['jobName'];
            $path = base64_decode($request->parameters['download']);

            if (Empty($name))
                $name = 'Unnamed';

            $raw_text = "Your volume export $name is finished and can be downloaded here:\r\n$path";
            $template_name = (Empty($mirror) ? 'success_name.html' : 'success_name_mirror.html');

            // If FTP then override the name with the ftp template.
            if (substr($path, 0, 4) == 'ftp:')
                $template_name = 'success_name_ftp.html';

            $html_text = file_get_contents($templates . $template_name);
            $html_text = str_replace(array("%name%", "%path%", "%mirror%", "%server%"), array($name, $path, $mirror, SERVER_PATH), $html_text);

            $mail = $this->createMail($email_addr, "Your volume extraction job is complete", $html_text, $raw_text);

            if(!$mail->send())
                return new Result(500, array('message' => 'failed to send mail', 'mail error' => $mail->ErrorInfo));

            // Delete job first when we have managed to send a mail correctly
            unlink($filepath);
        }
        elseif ($status === Status::FAILED) {
            $str = file_get_contents($filepath);
            $json = $this->decodeJson($str);
            $email_addr = $json['userEmail'];
            $name = $json['jobName'];
            $msg = base64_decode($request->parameters['reason']);

            if (Empty($name))
                $name = 'Unnamed';

            $raw_text = "Your volume export $name has failed and the reason given was:\r\n$msg";

            $msg = str_ireplace("\r\n", "<br>", $msg);  // Replace any newlines with <br> tags
            $msg = str_ireplace("\n", "<br>", $msg);

            $html_text = file_get_contents($templates . 'fail_name.html');
            $html_text = str_replace(array("%name%", "%msg%", "%server%"), array($name, $msg, SERVER_PATH), $html_text);

            $mail = $this->createMail($email_addr, "Your volume extraction job has failed", $html_text, $raw_text);

            if(!$mail->send())
                return new Result(500, array('message' => 'failed to send mail', 'mail error' => $mail->ErrorInfo));

            // Delete job first when we have managed to send a mail correctly
            unlink($filepath);
        }
        elseif ($status === Status::ABORTED) {
            rename($filepath, JOBS_PATH . $jobid . '.json');
        }

        return new Result(200, array('jobId' => $jobid));
    }

    private function createMail($to, $subject, $body_html, $alt_body) {
        $settings = parse_ini_file('..\\..\\settings.ini');

        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->isSMTP();                                // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = $settings['MAIL_HOST'];           // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = $settings['MAIL_USER'];       // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = $settings['MAIL_PASS'];       // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = $settings['MAIL_SECURE'];   // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = $settings['MAIL_PORT'];           // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->From = 'example@example.com';
        $mail->FromName = 'Example';
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->addReplyTo('noreply@example.com');

        $mail->isHTML(true);                        // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $body_html;
        $mail->AltBody = $alt_body;

        return $mail;
    }

    private function decodeJson($str) {
        $char = json_decode('"\uFEFF"');    // UTF-8 byte order mark
        return json_decode(trim(str_replace($char, '', $str)), true);   // Replace BOM if needed
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: It really depends how the mailer script is coded and how it's called. It feels like there's something that prevents the script from terminating properly but with no code or architecture details, there's no way of telling.

Comment: PHPMailer closes SMTP connections nicely when instances are destroyed (see `__destruct()` in the PHPMailer class), but it will keep connections open if `SMTPKeepAlive` is true, though PHP itself should close any TCP connections at the end of a script run anyway. If you're only sending occasional messages (i.e. not to a bulk list), don't use keepalive.

Comment: 50-100 connections should not trigger any kernel limits. Could be a firewall  (or DoS protection) problem on the SMTP server?

Comment: I have added my code, don't know if it helps any. SMTPKeepAlive is at least not set (i assume it defaults to false). Given that mails are only sent maybe at most every 15 minutes but typically only a few per day I have a hard time seeing ddos protection firing on it. We're talking 50-100 connections PER WEEK.